# how can i use httpclient too create a function that will keep the user login alive even after the app shut done?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a problem with this, because I want to keep the app logged in if the user just slide the switch that I have in the Login page. My question is how can I do this with the HttpClient in order to continue using the same session.

Thanks to anyone o could give me some info on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you want is to save the `token` that your API will retrieve if you make a successful login.

For this, you want to save, into storage, the token and you can use the [Xamarin.Essentials package](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials), most specifically the [Secure Storage Plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android)

```
try
{
  await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_token", "secret-oauth-token-value");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
}
```

And to retrieve it:

```
try
{
  var oauthToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("oauth_token");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
}
```

To Delete:

```
SecureStorage.Remove("oauth_token");
```